# I have changed my keyboard layout but it does not work

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Hello: I have recently changed the Spanish Dvorak keyboard layout on my laptop by editing its file (under /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols). If I open the file, it seems to have changed, but when I try to type out, not only is it not the new one, it is the English layout. And the same thing happens with the regular Spanish layout, so I seem to be stuck with the English one. I don't know what the cause is and it is not self-evident (there seems to be no difference between the Spanish file and any other language's -besides, obviously, the layout). I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, by the way.

Does anyone know what mistake I may have made and how to fix it?

Thank you :)

Comment: What option did you select to change the keyboard and what version Ubuntu? Please amend your question to include the answer to these questions.

Comment: I have added my Ubuntu version to the question, I am not sure I understand what you mean by what option I selected to change the keyboard

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarssong I have edited the question to add how I changed it. The reason I did it is that the default Dvorak layout is different from the one I was using on Windows (that's what I meant by there is no standard one) but that was besides the point, so I took it out for clarity's sake.

Comment: If you edited `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/es`, then please show us what you changed - preferably by attaching a diff compared to the original file.